# CUDA Cusp in Windows7

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cuda, cusp-library

I have trouble getting the [CUSP](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/) (version 0.2) library running under windows7 x64 and visual studio 2008. When including for example:

```
#include <cusp/hyb_matrix.h>
```

i get the following error:

```
error C2039: 'hypotf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include\cusp\complex.h  742
```

Anyone ever encountered this error or know how to get it running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX standard math libraries provide `hypot` and `hypotf`. Microsoft's libraries define `_hypot`and `hypotf`. You will probably have to patch `cusp/complex.h` to work around it. You might also want to post a bug report with the CUSP developers [here](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/issues/list), this seems like something they would want to fix.